# Coverity cov-build crashes in latest Debian testing (8.5 and 8.7 versions)

Tags: linux, coverity

Is anyone else having Coverity builder crash (segfault) under latest Debian testing?

Last time I was able to use it (am building coverity report for Blender) was in late October, with 8.5 version (iirc). When I tried again in late November, `cov-build` command crashes immediately reporting a segfault, even with mere `cov-build --help` command. Tried to update to latest version then (8.5.0.5), same result, and tried today 8.7.0 release, same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've been seeing reports of this for certain new builds of the Linux kernel, however we've been unable to reproduce the issue to-date. Have you engaged with Coverity's support? It's likely we will need detailed system configuration information in order to narrow down the culprit here - something has changed in the latest kernel/utilities/libraries that isn't playing nice with Coverity.

Comment: Not yet, wanted to know whether I was the only unlucky dev around or not first. ;) Will do now.

Comment: hrmm… so sent a mail to support@coverity.com, only reply I got was someone asking for my payed account info (which I do not have since am using Cov for OS project), and then nothing since two weeks… Is this correct email to contact, or do you have other for technical issues in open source projects?

Comment: For SCAN projects, I believe the email to contact for assistance is scan-admin@coverity.com

Comment: Thanks, will try that one then.

Answer (score 3):

Issue here is that Coverity scan tools are built for rather old Linux compatibility, and newer ones have the emulation of deprecated vsyscall disabled (since kernel 4.8).

So you have to start your kernel with the `vsyscall=emulate` parameter (easiest solution under Debian testing with Grub2 is to add this to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` setting of `/etc/default/grub`, and then run `grub-update`).

Thanks to the scan-admin@coverity.com team for their quick and precise answer! :)

Comment: Adding this parameter worked for me. Debian system with a 4.12 kernel